# What is the different between flag and report in ios app?

Tags: app-store, appstore-approval

I submitted an ios app to app store, the review team request me to implement a flag button and report button on images which users post. I'm not clear what flag button should to do? What is the different between flag button and report button?
Thanks,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 1):

It's basically the same. As your app contains user generated content, you need to have a way for users to report inappropriate content, which you then should remove, if it's indeed not "allowed". It's basically a "Report" button similar as seen on YouTube or every other social network.

[image]

It does not really matter how you call the button/link etc.